# Change password code error with Java & MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm building this component where I can change the password that is stored in my MySQL database using Java Eclipse. I have this typical system where you have to enter your old password and new password and have that old password checked to match the one in the system.

```
public class ChangePassword implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        JPasswordField oldPswrd = new JPasswordField(50);
        JPasswordField newPswrd = new JPasswordField(50);
        JLabel j = new JLabel("Type in old password: ");
        JLabel j2 = new JLabel("Type in new password: ");
        j.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        j2.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        
        Object[] message = {
                j, oldPswrd,
                j2, newPswrd,
            };
        
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message, 
                 "CHANGE PASSWORD", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
           char[] oldp = oldPswrd.getPassword();
           String oldP = String.valueOf(oldp);
           char[] p = newPswrd.getPassword();
           String newP = String.valueOf(p);
           System.out.println("New name: " + newP);
//// PROBLEM SEEMS TO START HERE ///////////////////////////////////////////
           try {    
               Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
               System.out.println("connection success!!");
               
               String sql = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_id = ? && user_password = ?";
               PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
               statement.setString(1, user_id);
               statement.setString(2, password);
               
               ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
               if (rs.next()){
                   String oldPassword = rs.getString("user_password");
                   if (oldP.equals(oldPassword)) {
                       String sql1 = "UPDATE user_info SET user_password = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
                       PreparedStatement statement1 = connection.prepareStatement(sql1);
                       statement1.setString(1, newP);
                       statement1.setString(2, user_id);
                       
                        int rows2 = statement1.executeUpdate();
                        if (rows2 > 0) {
                            System.out.println("UPDATE PASSWORD!");
                        }
                   }
               } else {
                   JLabel l = new JLabel("Old password does not match");
                   l.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 15));
                   l.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, l, "ERROR", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
               }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("& i oop");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
///////// PROBLEM SEEMS TO END HERE   ///////////////////////////////////////////
           frame.setVisible(false);
           new UserMain(user_id, name, newP);
    }
        
    }
}
```

I have this table with a row of data already set in as a test. However, whenever I try to change the password - typing in the correct old password and typing in another new one - it always shows

> old password does not match

There's no syntax or connection errors so I figured the problem is a logic error or something I couldn't catch. Also, the java portions work fine, I've checked those already. The problem seems to be between the `try` and `catch` parts of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`password` is your database password, not one of the user passwords. Change

```
statement.setString(2, password);
```

to

```
statement.setString(2, oldP);
```

Comment: You found the problem! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Where are you taking this "username" and "password" from?

Also you are passing the same "password" variable to find the user that is using for the DB connection. I think it should be change to "oldP ".

Comment: The username and password are both passed from my other function that this function stems off from. And yes, that seems to be the problem. Thanks so much!